# D3.js Line chart tooltip at points

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to add tooltip to [this](https://codepen.io/7deepakpatil/pen/ObvqXX?editors=0010) chart.
I am referring to [this](http://bl.ocks.org/bobmonteverde/2070069) and [this](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369) example

The issue is that their are no unique points on the line in the SVG it just has the path tag.

```
 svg.selectAll("dot")   
    .data(data)         
.enter().append("circle")                               
    .attr("r", 5)       
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })       
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.close); })     
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
        div.transition()        
            .duration(200)      
            .style("opacity", .9);      
        div .html(formatTime(d.date) + "<br/>"  + d.close)  
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
        })                  
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
        div.transition()        
            .duration(500)      
            .style("opacity", 0);   
    });
```

Like the above code selects the dot on the SVG but I dont have any specific element to bind the tooltip.

Can any one help me in this as I am new to d3.js.

Answer (score 2):

you should take d.value for y:

```
.attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
```

and now append new element on mouseover:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {      
        svg.append("text")
          .text(d.value)
          .attr('class', 'tooltip').style("font-size","10px")
          .attr("x", x(d.date))
          .attr("y", y(d.value))
          .attr('fill', 'red');
        })                  
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
        d3.selectAll('.tooltip').remove();
    });
```

Comment: ........I tried your solution but got this error...Cannot read property 'value' of undefined [here is the codepen with your solution](https://codepen.io/7deepakpatil/pen/ObvqXX?editors=0010)